# Is there a way to extrude the height of mapbox Point on the map?

Tags: mapbox

Is there a way to extrude the height of mapbox Point on the map?
Having the following example:

```
 map.addSource("markers", {
        "type": "geojson",
        "data": {
            "type": "FeatureCollection",
            "features": [{
                "type": "Feature",
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [14.422063225409431,50.08273361716846]
                },
                "properties": {
                    "height": 12,
                    "base_height": 10,
                    "title": "Mapbox DC",
                    "marker-symbol": "spaceti-maintenance"
                }
            }, {
                "type": "Feature",
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [14.421896271941648,50.08259946060207]
                },
                "properties": {
                    "height": 12,
                    "base_height": 10,
                    "title": "Mapbox SF",
                    "marker-symbol": "spaceti-maintenance"
                }
            }]
        }
    });


map.addLayer({
    "id": "markers",
    "source": "markers",
    //"type": "symbol",
    "type":"fill-extrusion",
    // "layout": {
    //    "icon-image": "{marker-symbol}",
    //    "text-field": "{title}",
    //    "text-font": ["Open Sans Semibold", "Arial Unicode MS Bold"],
    //    "text-offset": [0, 0.6],
    //    "text-anchor": "top"
    // },
    "paint": {
        // See the Mapbox Style Spec for details on property functions
        // https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-style-spec/#types-function
        "fill-extrusion-color": "#424242",
        "fill-extrusion-height": {
            // Get fill-extrusion-height from the source "height" property.
            "property": "height",
            "type": "identity"
        },
        "fill-extrusion-base": {
            // Get fill-extrusion-base from the source "base_height" property.
            "property": "base_height",
            "type": "identity"
        },
        // Make extrusions slightly opaque for see through indoor walls.
        "fill-extrusion-opacity": 0.90
      }
});
```

am I able to use both layout and paint properties of the layer assuming that I want to have marker with custom icon + extrusion height? I am building indoor navigation with multiple floor, that is the reason.

Comment: Have you managed to make it work? Currently having the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52359776/data-driven-3d-extrusion-with-mapbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

​It's not possible at this time to extrude points, however, you can convert these to (small) circles and extrude them based on your values. Looks like some similar requests for point cloud support is here:
​https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/3450 so you may be able to follow the progress should it makes its way into new releases.

Comment: Would you mind adding an example on how to extrude circles based on the values I have. I have asked the question here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52359776/data-driven-3d-extrusion-with-mapbox) as well if you'd rather answer it there to get the extra karma.